# How to view my previous questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I wanted to know how to view my *previous questions*. Also, are the questions we ask, get deleted in a small(/whatever) period of time?

Comment: Your user profile is [here](http://superuser.com/users/573419/gourabo).  Be sure you read the help center though, it will explain how to navigate, and if you follow its guidelines you won't end up asking low quality questions

Comment: @Ramhound thanks there, ***ha ha ha*** I do not like - a- read, but that's what I have to do.

Comment: You are welcome not to take my advice.  Just don't be shocked when your questions are not well received.  *I don't see the humor in my suggestion.*

Answer (score 1):

This is your [user profile](https://superuser.com/users/573419/gourabo). It has what you ask for.

As for deletions, well, if a question dosen't meet quality standards, it could be closed. If an answer is not good, it could be downvoted or flagged for deletion.

Looking at your past questions, reading the help sounds like a good idea. I'd also suggest not answering questions that are likely to be closed.

Enough deleted questions or answer can lead to question and answer bans, and no one can really help you there.

Comment: Thanks, I am actually a ***new user***, not only for this site but as a computer user.      Not to be proud of, well I be good at this things with time.